# Trying to understand array notations

Tags: c, arrays

in the following code :

```
int main()
{

    int i = 15, j = 1;
    int *a[] = {&i, &j};
    printf("%d", (*a)[0]);
    return 0;

}
```

the output of `(*a)[0]` is `15` (value of i) however when I tried to check `(*a)[1]` it gives a garbage value. I would expect that the same expression should work for all the entries in the array however it works only for the first element in the array.

Comment: `*a` is `&i` , `(*a)[0]` is  `*(&i + 0)`, `(*a)[1]` is `*(&i + 1)` it's UB.

Comment: (*a) gives you the first element of the array (same as a[0]) the following [0] gives the int at that address. While (*a)[1] is the int at the address after the address of i

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you have declared array of pointers. At first you should know the various representation of array. How a[i] is calculate? a gives you the base address of array.

```
a[ i ]  = *(a+i)
(*a)[0] = *(*a+0)
(*a)[1] = *(*a+1)

Thus the value of (*a)[0] = *(address of i + 0) = Value of i  
And the value of  (*a)[1] = *(address of i + 1) = value at the location of (add of i + 2) i.e. a garbage value.
```

In above problem you can get the value correctly if you use *( a[ 0 ] ) and *( a[1] ).

Comment: How do you figure `*(address of i + 1)` is the “value at the location of (add of i + 2)”? Where does the 2 come from? Are you assuming the size of an `int` is 2, so you mean 2 bytes?

Comment: @EricPostpischil, yes i am assuming the sizeof(int) = 2. That's why i have added 2.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't try `(*a)[0]` and `(*a)[1]` in the first place. You should try `*(a[0])` and `*(a[1])`.

You have an array of `int *`'s called `a`. `a` has two elements, `a[0]` and `a[1]`. `a[0]` is `&i` and `a[1]` is `&j`. Therefore `*(a[0])` is `i` and `*(a[1])` is `j`.

Comment: This does not explain why, which is the main question.

Comment: No need to use complex syntax. `*a[0]` is enough.

Comment: @RubenSerrate It has unnecessary noise which makes code harder to read.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Well, if `a` is not a pointer, starting by `(*a)` and then accessing `(*a)[1]` does not seem to make much sense to me. Doing it the right way, you avoid facing the problems which the OP observes by doing it the wrong way.

Comment: Maybe once you're used to it, but *(a[0]) helps you understand the concept better, I think.

Comment: I like `*(a[0])` because it is more readable and less error prone. However, this is the operation I'd typically split in two separate steps, for extra readability and maintainability. In any case, I can't really tell because I don't remeber the last time I declared a `int *a[]`.

Comment: `*(a[0])` is fine, but you should still mention the `*a[0]`. Arrays of pointers are so common in C, that you will litter the code with unnecessary brackets otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused over the semantics of pointers here (lots of people are)

```
int x[2]; // an array of two ints
int *y[2]; // an array of two int pointers.

typeof(x[0]) == int // this isn't really valid C code
typeof(*x)   == int // arrays are (pretty much) pointers

typeof(y[0]) == int*
typeof(*y)   == int*
typeof(**y)  == int
```

Comment: Arrays are *not* pointers. They will decay into pointers in some circumstances.

Comment: You can treat them like pointers most of the time, the only time they don't really function like pointers is trying to reassign them.

Comment: ...and the way `sizeof` works on them, and the way that memory is allocated for them. Pointers are always about memory address being stored, array are always about data being stored. There is not anything in common with them apart from some syntatic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

try this one below, you will better understand whats going on, this is not an answer to your question but should help you understand.

oops, you will have to assign the array name to a pointer, you wont be allowed to increment the array name by this ++ since its not a variable,

```
 int **s = a;
(*++s)[0] this will print 1.
```

since the array name points to the first element, this will increment it by 1(now it will point to the second element), then dereference it, and take the [0] element of the memory pointed to by (*++a)